# Ubuntu server 12.04 (Openstack) Installation

Tags: 12.04, server, cloud

i need help regarding build a private cloud using Ubuntu server 12.04. I have 3 pc with following configuration

1-Ram - 4 gb
2-Processor - Intel i5 3470 @3.20 Ghz
3-Network Card - Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
4-Disk Drive - WDC WD5000AAKX-08ERMA0 ATA Device

Please tell me step by step procedure to build a private cloud using these 3.

Comment: Don't use Ubuntu server 12.04.  That is old and not reasonable to use for a new setup.  Use 14.04 and there are lots of examples for seting up a cloud step by step.

Comment: can u please provide be the link which provides step by step setting of cloud

Comment: There are many, you can look at Ubuntus own web page where all steps into deploying are located.  Or you can use OpenStack:s own dokumentation where all steps also are described.  Also IBM have an OpenStack distribution that can be installed on top of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is where Google search gave for searching with `OpenStack Ubuntu 14.04`.

- Installing The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack
- OpenStack for Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud
- OpenStack installations methods on Ubuntu, four different ways: http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack
- OpenStacks own documentations of OpenStack: http://docs.openstack.org/
- OpenStack Installation Guide for Ubuntu 14.04: http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/
- IBM's version of OpenStack: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/servicemanagement/cvm/sce/index.html

Yes, it is much to choose from, I know.  Yes, it is complicated, I know.

Comment: i have installed oracle virtual box 4.3 on windows 8, then i created 3 virtual machine such as controller, network and compute. after configure static ip for all of these vm i have open controller vm, and executed the command  sudo apt-get update but instead of update i got the output as : could not resolve in.archieve.ubuntu.com, security.ubuntu.com

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with the network.  You could start by see what `getent hosts askubuntu.com` gives.  And check if you have a proper ipadress with `ip addr` and if you have a proper router set up with `ip route`.